# __init__ within class supposedly missing arguments?

Tags: python, class, init

```
class FoodItem:
    def __init__(self, item_name, amount_fat, amount_carbs, amount_protein, num_servings):
        self.item_name = "None"
        self.amount_fat = 0.0
        self.amount_carbs = 0.0
        self.amount_protein = 0.0
        self.num_servings = 0.0
       
    def get_calories(self, num_servings):
        # Calorie formula
        calories = ((self.fat * 9) + (self.carbs * 4) + (self.protein * 4)) * num_servings;
        return calories
       
    def print_info(self):
        print('Nutritional information per serving of {}:'.format(self.name))
        print('   Fat: {:.2f} g'.format(self.fat))
        print('   Carbohydrates: {:.2f} g'.format(self.carbs))
        print('   Protein: {:.2f} g'.format(self.protein))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    food_item1 = FoodItem()
   
    item_name = input()
    amount_fat = float(input())
    amount_carbs = float(input())
    amount_protein = float(input())
   
    food_item2 = FoodItem(item_name, amount_fat, amount_carbs, amount_protein)
      
    num_servings = float(input())
      
    food_item1.print_info()
    print('Number of calories for {:.2f} serving(s): {:.2f}'.format(num_servings, 
                          food_item1.get_calories(num_servings)))
                           
    print()
                           
    food_item2.print_info()
    print('Number of calories for {:.2f} serving(s): {:.2f}'.format(num_servings, 
                          food_item2.get_calories(num_servings)))
```

Results in the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    food_item1 = FoodItem()
TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'item_name', 'amount_fat', 'amount_carbs', 'amount_protein', and 'num_servings'
```

I'm not spotting an obvious error, but I'm new to initializing classes. The error seems to say that I'm missing arguments within the original **init**, but considering they were initialized to 0/'none' values, I don't understand that.

Perhaps someone can catch the error?

Comment: `food_item1 = FoodItem()`. You need to pass arguments here just like you did the second time.

Comment: You're initializing the class members not the function arguments, if you want change you functions to have default parameters. e.g. `__init__(self, item_name=0, amount_fat=0...`

Comment: The error is **entirely clear**, `FoodItem()` provides 0 arguments, but you wrote `__init__` to require 5 positional arguments, enumerated by the error. What do you not understand exactly? Why do you *expect* `food_item1 = FoodItem()` to work?

Comment: Note, your arguments to `__init__` aren't used, and instead, you just initialize the variables to hardcoded values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your class with **ALL** the arguments: `item_name`, `amount_fat`, `amount_carbs`, `amount_protein` and `num_servings`.

```
# here, you have to provide the arguments
food_item1 = FoodItem()
...
# and here, you are missing the 'num_servings' argument
food_item2 = FoodItem(item_name, amount_fat, amount_carbs, amount_protein)
```

Just in case, you can provide default values to an argument like so:

```
# here, the argument will default to '0' if you do not provide a value.
class Example: 
    def __init__(self, argument=0): 
        self.argument = argument

example = Example()
print(example.argument)

>>> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not saying what to match for example self.amount_fat with which argument you are talking about.
You should write:
self.amount_fat = amount_fat

And then announce was self.amount_fat is, otherwise your program will not know where to read.

```
def __init__(self, item_name, amount_fat, amount_carbs, amount_protein, num_servings):
    self.item_name = item_name
    self.amount_fat = amount_fat
    self.amount_carbs = amount_carbs
    self.amount_protein = amount_protein
    self.num_servings = num_servings
```

You can then add what you coded initially.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently with the same initialization problem. Essentially you are supposed to add the default to the initial parameters.

When i realized that I was faced with an issue of 8/10 test passing with the issue being the name. All I had to do was add a single quote to the name.

So, my code looks like this

```
def __init__(self,item_name='None',amount_fat=0.0,amount_carbs=0.0,amount_protein=0.0,num_servings=0.0):
    self.name = item_name
    self.fat = amount_fat
    self.carbs = amount_carbs
    self.protein = amount_protein
    self.sevings = num_servings
```